# Two keys are to be pressed and released subsequently, AutoHotKey sends me a key of my choice

Tags: automation, keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey, keymapping

I have to press two keys:

When the 'a' is pressed and released, thenafter 'b' is pressed and released and finally AutoHotKey sends me a key of my choice.

Edit: like:

a & b::c

Here, I am not pressing both keys at the same time, but one after another, and need c in resulting output.

Comment: You need to show your script.  Talk about what you have tried.  And try to make this into a question.

Comment: We cannot understand what you are asking in this question. Please try to be more clear about where it is you are needing help. Showing a script that you've written and pointing out where it is going wrong is a great start.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
#NoEnv
#Warn
#SingleInstance Force
#UseHook
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%
SendMode Input

a::fCheck()

fCheck() {
    oIH := InputHook("L1")
    oIH.Start()
    oIH.Wait()
    If (oIH.Input == "b")
        Send c
}
```